# Oracle, show only rows where no numeric values appear

Tags: sql, oracle

I have column X with values like:

```
619 19th St S, Oslo, AL 3522310, Spain
4538 S Harvard Ave, Roma, OK 74135, Germany
Golaa, CA , USA
Piri, SO, Italy
```

And I would like to filter only those, where I see no number in column so the outcome of the query should be:

```
Golaa, CA , USA
Piri, SO, Italy
```

Comment: Your question title says you want to show only rows that include numeric characters.  Your question text says the exact opposite.

Comment: You are right, I will try to edit it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Regular Expressions for pattern matching in Oracle.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  yourTable
WHERE
  NOT REGEXP_LIKE(x, '[0-9]+')
```

This will exclude any rows that have one or more numeric digits in column x.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a regular expression, but I think this is simpler:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE NOT REGEXP_LIKE(x, '[0-9]');
```

You can also do this without regular expressions:

```
WHERE x = TRANSLATE(x, 'a0123456789', 'a')
```

Comment: I voted up for translate cuz It works little more faster. The difference is shown on large amount of data. But you forget to specify x as first parameter of translate function.

Answer (score 0):

```
with s as (
select '619 19th St S, Oslo, AL 3522310, Spain' str from dual union all
select '4538 S Harvard Ave, Roma, OK 74135, Germany' from dual union all
select 'Golaa, CA , USA' from dual union all
select 'Piri, SO, Italy' from dual)
select *
from s
where str = translate(str, 'z1234567890', 'z');

STR
------------------------------
Golaa, CA , USA
Piri, SO, Italy
```